# i tried to take mysqldump using crontab it's not worked?

Tags: shell, cron, mysql, cron-task

Here the below code for taking mysqldump using cronjobs but its failed to make a dump.

```
[client]
user=testuser
pass=******

2 * * * * mysqldump --default-extra-file="/home/admin/Desktop/shellscript/.my.cnf" -u testuser -dbname test > /home/admin/Desktop/shellscript/testbackup.sql
```

Comment: Do you have `[client]` in the crontab? That's not valid... I also don't see a reference to the `-dbname` argument in the `mysqldump` documentation, where did you get that from?

Comment: @Carpetsmoder 2 * * * * mysqldump --default-extra-file="/home/admin/Desktop/shellscript/.my.cnf" --all-databases > /home/admin/Desktop/shellscript/testbackup.sql

Comment: @Carpetsmoket above one also not worked

Comment: What do you mean, "Not worked"? Do you get an error? Do you get the wrong output? Does this command work from your commandline? Do you see anything in your system's cron logfile? You also haven't answered the question whether the `[client]` line is in the crontab file.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker yeah its worked in command line same command i tried using cronjobs it doesnot make dump

Comment: So, I will ask you again, is the `[client]` line in the crontab? That's not valid syntax for a crontab, as far as I know.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker no [client] in crontab